# Zoom UIView and all the contents in it

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, uiview

I am new to develop iOS frameworks/library. I have to develop a framework to zoom the pages of an iOS application. I have a view based application and some elements like `UIButton` and `UITextField` in it. When I do a pinch zoom/double tap, the `UIView` and all its contents should be zoomed(pan and zoom) accordingly.

My idea is to create a template view, which acts as a normal `UIView`(I mean that I can add components and sub views to the view), which has the feature to pan and zoom. Please note that all its components(`UIButton`, `UITextField`) are also zoomed accordingly.

First of all I'd like to know whether it is possible. Please do give me some suggestions to achieve it.

Comment: `UIScrollView` has all of this functionality already made.

Comment: I am aware that I can add a `UIImageView` to a `UIScrollView` to zoom it. Does the same works to zoom a `UITextField`/`UIButton`?

Comment: @iPhoneAkilan you should put all your components in one uiscrollview, then use zooming of the control. it can works

Comment: Yes, this is how I did it with every single view, and my app is zoomable in about 80% of its locations.

Comment: Thanks @borrrden and chancy. Let me try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Scrollviews delegate to return the view to be zoomed

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return viewTobeZoomed;
}
```

Also u can control the max and min zoom values as

```
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1.01;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=5;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale=1.01;
```